# sbt deb package file name format is wrong

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

sbt debian:packageBin command generates my deb package as:

my-package-1.0.deb

The name and version should be delimited by an underscore "_" like my-package_1.0
The architecture type should be appended like my-package_1.0_all.deb

How can I get this instead of renaming my deb file?

Answer (score 1):

How are you publishing your `deb` file?   You can always alter the "pattern" used when deploying to match your desired layout:

```
val debPublishPattern = "[module]_[revision]_all.[ext]"

publishTo in Debian := Some(Resolver.file("local-deb-repo", file("/path/to/repo"))(Patterns(debPublishPattern)))
```

This should let you run `debian:publish` to push the deb file with your desired format wherever you'd like.  Also, we don't do it currently, but we can add to the Ivy configuration the "architecture" as a property so you can have the pattern be exactly: `[module]_[revision]_[arch].[ext]`.  If you need that please open a ticket.

In terms of naming, given how a lot of deb repositories work, the name is less important than the index, so we assume your publishing will rename/index as appropriate.